# Visual Studio 2010 tab close button

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I'm used to having the 'x' close button that closes each tab you have open positioned on the right, the way it is in VS 2008. In 2010, each tab has it's own 'x' close. I like this but would also like to have the old close button too. Anyway of doing this?

Comment: good question, annoys me too...

Comment: You're both lucky to have this problem.  I'll probably be stuck in 2008 for 5 years.

Comment: @mootinator: You're lucky. When given the choice, I go with 08 every time.

Comment: God I agree 100% with this question.  It's SO annoying having a close button on every single tab, I close tabs accidentally all the time!  I guess they were copying Google Chrome.  What a terrible decision.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's an extension that will let you do this: [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef). After installing, if you go to `Tools->Options...->Productivity Power Tools->General` you can check the "Show close button at end of well" box. If you want the close button in both places, also check the "Show close button" box.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Yes, the Pro Power Tools is the extension you want to control the close button placement. You also get a lot of other really useful extensions with this (although you can disable any that you don't want).

Comment: Thanks. This also works for VS2012, using the [new plugin version](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd)